# cellvariable*Diffusion in fipy

Tags: pde, fipy, non-linear

I am trying to solve the following [coupled pde's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsSY1.png) in fipy. I tried the following

```
eq1 = (DiffusionTerm(coeff=1, var=f)-f*DiffusionTerm(coeff=1, var=phi)
       +f-f**3 == 0)
eq2 = (2*DiffusionTerm(coeff=f, var=phi)+f*DiffusionTerm(coeff=1, var=phi)
       == 0)
eq = eq1 & eq2
eq.solve()
```

but it does not like "f*DiffusionTerm(coeff=1, var=phi)" and I get the error.
"TermMultiplyError: Must multiply terms by int or float." Is there a way that I can implement a cell variable times a diffusion term?

Comment: ok I tried ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=DiffusionTerm(coeff=1, var=phi) and I get an error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'DiffusionTerm' and 'int'"

Comment: Is there a way I can iteratively solve this? With fipy?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the following will work in FiPy,

```
from fipy import CellVariable, DiffusionTerm, Grid1D
mesh = Grid1D(nx=10)
var = CellVariable(mesh=mesh)
# eqn = var * DiffusionTerm(coeff=1)
eqn = ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=DiffusionTerm(coeff=1))
eqn.solve(var)
```

They both simply don't make sense with respect to the discretization in the finite volume method. Regardless, you can use the following identity to rewrite the term of interest

[image]

Basically, instead of using

```
var * DiffusionTerm(coeff=1)
```

you can use

```
DiffusionTerm(coeff=var) - var.grad.mag**2
```

Giving a regular diffusion term and an extra explicit source term.