# How to represent these non-standard pdes with FiPy?

Tags: pde, fipy

I am trying to solve a set of PDEs with FiPy, but not sure how to represent the equations: [see the PDEs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58KkS.png).

The terms give me trouble are those in red rectangle and blue rectangle. The one in red rectangle is a convection term times a function depending on x, T1 and T2; The one in blue rectangle is a transient term times another function depending on x, T1 and T2.

I couldn't find any example including this kind of terms. Could you please give me some suggestions, or share me an example?

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is similar to [cellvariable*Diffusion in fipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68552591/cellvariablediffusion-in-fipy), but for convection instead of diffusion. The solution is the same though. Use,

[image]

to convert the red terms into a convection term with a coefficient of f and a source term.

For the blue terms do exactly the same to get a transient term with a coefficient and a source term.

---

Edit: if we assume that [image] then we can still use

[image]

and approximate explicitly (with f as a variable in FiPy and use `grad`). However, we can take it further and use,

[image]

and approximate the final [image] explicitly.

Again, we can go even further with,

[image]

Again the last term can be solved explicitly. Depending on the form of `f` the last them *should* become more insignificant and thus, the explicitness less of an issue.

Comment: However, the f functions depends on \phi, so I cannot use this method...

Comment: Ok, I've tried to address this in the edit. One can still use the initial equation if f_x is evaluated explicitly. However, this doesn't seem as satisfactory as using one of the other identities.